# IntelliJ can't find any LibGDX packages?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I have just switched to Ubuntu and I've installed IntelliJ IDEA 14 Community Edition. When I imported my existing project, I found that IntelliJ can't seem to find any of the LibGDX dependencies. I installed Gradle beforehand. I've tried using the Gradle wrapper included with the IntelliJ project to and saying `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies`, but this doesn't seem to do much of anything. My external TweenEngine packages were loaded just fine. It seems to only be with the LibGDX packages that IntelliJ is having a problem with. I do not wish to have IntelliJ see my project as a Gradle Project, as then it will have to sync. I prefer to do things myself in that regard.

My guess is that Gradle isn't installing the LibGDX dependencies, but I'm not entirely sure why that would be happening. Shouldn't `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies` install them? The errors I get are all the same as this one, just with different package names and different line numbers:

```
Error:(7, 24) java: package com.badlogic.gdx does not exist
```

The line numbers correlate to my LibGDX class imports, so this is what leads me to believe that Gradle is not installing the dependencies.

When I imported the project, I selected the build.gradle file. I have the local.properties file pointing to a valid Android SDK.

If you want a specific look at the project and would like more detail than I have provided, feel free to check out the source code: http://bitbucket.org/Sonic2kk/mr.-ballguy/

What could be causing these errors and how can I correct them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the android sdk. If that doesn't work, try reinstalling IntelliJ.

Also, try linking your IntelliJ project to IntelliJ's Gradle plugin.

Comment: This fixed my problem! I linked my project to IntelliJ and then unlinked it (I don't like keeping projects linked in IntelliJ as I mentioned, so I was hesitant to try this. However I ran out of alternatives)

Comment: @Eamonn I'm happy that I was able to solve your problem. I've been having the same problem and then I remembered this haha.

Comment: Another also is make sure your gradle plugin is enable/installed. Go to plugins and and enable gradle. From the main launch window "Configuration"->"Plugins"-> check gradle